# ¿Cómo puedo restar en php (restando cantidades de la base de datos de 2 tablas diferentes)? :C mi código esta abajo

Tags: php, sql

Intento hacer la resta pero el resultado me da 0

````
 <?php
      include "dbd.php";
       ```
        archivo validar 
        ```
         ```
       aquí mando a llamar a mis 2 tablas llamadas "articulos" y "pedidos"
         ```
      $id = intval($_GET['id']);
      $cantidad = "SELECT cantidad FROM pedidos WHERE Id_formulario = '.$id.'";
      $stock = "SELECT stock FROM articulos WHERE Idarticulo = '.$id.'";
      $res = intval($stock) - intval($cantidad);
       ```
      insertar $res en donde esta el stock
       ```
````

y Aqui hace el UPDATE actualizando mi tabla de articulos donde tengo el stock

````
          $sql = 'UPDATE articulos SET stock = ' . $res . ' WHERE Idarticulo = '.$id.'';
            if ($link->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "$res";
             } else {
           echo "ERROR";
        }
       mysqli_close($link);
        ```
       los registros me los guarda como "0"
         ```
````

Y aquí termina mi codigo soy nuevo :(

Comment: que has investigado

Comment: El problema que tienes es que estás definiendo unas consultas, pero no las estás ejecutando... son simples `strings`. `string - string = 0` (menos en PHP 8 que lanza una error)... Por eso siempre te da 0... porque no estás ejecutando las consultas y estás intentando restar los strings en vez de los resultados de las consultas.